# IBM Worklight - Dojo ComboBox not closing during transition to another view

Tags: combobox, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I have developed a Worklight Hybrid application using Dojo. In my project I have a ComboBox created using `dojox.mobile.combobox.`

My problem is when opening the ComboBox in one page and navigating to a view the dropdown part of the combobox stays visible.

Comment: Can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

See this dojo-toolkit discussion thread describing the same phenomena: http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Dropdown-combobox-doesn-t-dissapear-tt3992812.html#none

Download this sample project containing an implemented workaround (with great help from the Dojo Mobile team developers): [Worklight 6.1.0-based Dojo app with ComboBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0f68roh9ffyvmj4/Dojo_ComboBox.zip)

The solution is as follows in the require function:

```
require([ "dojo/_base/connect", "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/ready", "dojo/dom", 
        "dijit/registry", "dojo/parser", "dojox/mobile", 
        "dojox/mobile/Heading", "dijit/form/DataList", "dojox/mobile/ComboBox", "dojox/mobile/View", 
        "dojox/mobile/Button", "dojox/mobile/RoundRectList", "dojox/mobile/ListItem" ],
        function(connect, win, ready, dom, registry) {
            ready(function() {
                var combo1 = registry.byId("combo1");
                var combo2 = registry.byId("combo2");
                connect.subscribe("/dojox/mobile/beforeTransitionIn",
                    function(view, moveTo, dir, transition, context, method){
                        combo1.closeDropDown();
                        combo2.closeDropDown();
                });
            }
        );
    });
```